# How does the "Compare" Node works in Geometry Nodes for checking the Position of geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on a node setup for spawning windows on the faces of buildings. Since I only wanted to spawn along faces alligned with the X and Y axis, not curved or angled, I tried to separate the geometry with the **"Compare"** and **"Position"** Nodes.  This is the setup:

[image]

[image]

The problem is, I'm not really sure how the **"Compare"** node works, and even though I got it to work after messing with different Epsilon values, I don't know what the values actually mean. The setup currently work with mostly rectangular buildings, but I need to input new Epsilon values for different buildings, and it won't work on more complex shapes.

I read the documentation on the Blender website, but it didn't help much. What does the *"epsilon"* and *"value"* in the node stand for, and is there a better way to set them up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compare node outputs either 0 or 1. It outputs 1 if the difference of the two input values are less than epsilon. Used to check if two values are equal within a certain tolerance.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So the node is comparing the X value of the position Vector agaisnt the input Value and the difference agaisnt the Epsilon. So it's only really selecting based on a radius originating from the origin. Not really the solution I needed in the end. Thanks for the reply.